# Cannot find variable navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to use react navigation but getting this error
[image]

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import{StyleSheet,Text,View,TextInput} from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity,FlatList,ScrollView,} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import LegalInformation from './LegalInformation'
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

export default function App(){
    const[menu,menupeople]=useState([
        {name:'My Account',key:1},
        {name:'Notification Settings',key:2},
        {name:'Clear Cache',key:3},
        {name:'Legal Information',key:4},
        {name:'Rate App Tak',key:5},
        {name:'Version',key:6},
        {name:'About',key:7},
    ])
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <ScrollView>
            
            {menu.map((item)=>{
                return(
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(LegalInformation)}
               key={item.key}
               >
                   <Text style={styles.item}
                   >{item.name}</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
                )
            })}
          
            </ScrollView> 
        </View>
    )
    
}
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        paddingTop:40,
        paddingHorizontal:20,
        alignItems:'center'
    }
})
```

I read the documentation of react navigation and installed all the dependencies imported the required dependencies but this does not seem to work any tip

Comment: The `navigation` variable is never defined anywhere and you try to use it in the onPress handler, hence the error.

Comment: Where do you define the variable `navigation`?  Did you mean to import it from one of the `@react-navigation` packages?

Comment: @David where should i define variable navigation i am pretty new to this

Comment: @RishailSiddiqui: Wherever you need it to be defined.  Currently it's only referenced within the scope of the `onPress` handler, so currently that's the only scope where it needs to be defined.

Comment: You should follow this documentation to get started with navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

You should get the `navigation` from `props` like

```
export default function App(props){    
let {navigation}=props;
//your code
}
```

but first make sure that your component is wrapped by `NavigationContainer`. Read [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started) for more detailed info.